# show images of different dimension in center of a div of fixed size

Tags: html, css

I am grabbing news from different website & want to show them as show as [example](http://jsfiddle.net/r55Er/1/)

http://jsfiddle.net/r55Er/1/

Problem is with the image, Images associate with articles are of different dimension.

I have an image container 'div' of 80x80 pixels and i want to display image in center both vertically & horizontally

I want to show image in best possible way ...

I would appreciate help in this regarding or how i show image in best possible way without hurting the design.

```
<div class="news-wrapper">
    <div class="news-image"><img class="img" src="http://gulfnews.com/media/img/gulfnews_logo.png"/></div>
     <div class="news-title"> News Title 1</div>
     <div class="news-source"> Source 1</div>
     <div class="news-description"> Some Descriptionn</div>
</div>
<div class="news-wrapper">
    <div class="news-image"><img class="img" src="http://i.cdn.turner.com/cnn/.e/img/3.0/global/header/intl/hdr-globe-central.gif"/></div>
     <div class="news-title"> News Title 1</div>
     <div class="news-source"> Source 1</div>
     <div class="news-description"> Some Descriptionn</div>
</div>
<div class="news-wrapper">
    <div class="news-image"><img class="img" src="http://news.bbcimg.co.uk/media/images/65881000/jpg/_65881249_65881241.jpg"/></div>
     <div class="news-title"> News Title 1</div>
     <div class="news-source"> Source 1</div>
     <div class="news-description"> Some Descriptionn</div>
</div>
<div class="news-wrapper">
    <div class="news-image"><img class="img" src="http://www.zawya.com/images/cia/large/130213070447ptjw.jpg"/></div>
     <div class="news-title"> News Title 1</div>
     <div class="news-source"> Source 1</div>
     <div class="news-description"> Some Descriptionn</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273338/how-to-properly-vertically-align-an-image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `position:absolute` your images and `position:relative` yourr `news-wrapper` and then give `top:0;bottom:0;margin:auto` to your image. I edited your fiddle and you can check it here [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r55Er/2/)

Answer (score 3):

if your images are relatively around 80 x 80 pixels, just apply them has a background of your cell. This way it will always be centered .. never overflow .. etc etc.

```
<div class="news-wrapper">
    <div class="news-image" style="background-image:url('http://www.zawya.com/images/cia/large/130213070447ptjw.jpg';"></div>
     <div class="news-title"> News Title 1</div>
     <div class="news-source"> Source 1</div>
     <div class="news-description"> Some Descriptionn</div>
</div>

.news-image {
    width:80px;
    height:80px;
    background-attachment:scroll;
    background-color:transparent;
    background-position:50% 50%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To align an image vertically in the middle, try to set line-height equal to height for the container and set dispaly inline-block with "vertical-align middle" for the image. To align horizontally, just set "text-align center" for the image container.

```
.image-container {
     text-align: center;
     line-height: 80px; /* equals to container height */
}
img {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[Here's modified sample in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r55Er/4/)